# Get click event of bootstrap dropdown created dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am dynamically creating a drop down based on values from my database within datatables. I have however hit a snag since I cannot get the click event on my elements. I would like to have an Edit and Delete on the drop down.

```
<div class="btn-group orderactions">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="btn mini dropdown-toggle">
<i class="icon-cogs"></i> Tools <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ">
<li><a value="1" class="editvar" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Edit</a></li>
<li><a value="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove deletevar"></i> Delete</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

That segment is created dynamically and changed when table is refreshed. How do I get the .editvar and .deletevar click events?

Comment: What are `.editvar` and `.deletevar`?

Comment: paste more code for the dynamically created elements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing. You are actually missing the `.editvar` and `.deletevar` in your code. But if you want to bind a click event on a dynamicly added `.editvar` element, this should work :

```
$(document).on('click', '.editvar', function(){
    /* your code */
});
```

Comment: So the only way I can reference it is using the $(document) tag?

Comment: No, you can use it with any parent : `$('div#mydiv').on('click', '.editvar', function(){});`